# An error occurs when creating a spring project. : J2EE Component Mapping Update

Tags: spring, eclipse

When creating a spring project, an error occurs.

Project creation works normally, but this error keeps popping up every few minutes:

`an internal error occured during: J2EE Component Mapping Update`

So it says we need to update the components, so I searched for a way to update the software, but I don't know...

I think it's a way to click the install new software menu on the Help menu, write url, and then update the corresponding part.

I found a way to update from the regular Eclipse version, but I can't find a way to update from Spring tools 4....

*FYI, The error does not disappear when the spring is turned off and on again.

Comment: Could you please attach the full stack trace

Comment: @Maxim, this error is coming from the IDE, not from the code.